# Nltk french tokenizer in python not working

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

Why is the french tokenizer that comes with python not working for me?
Am I doing something wrong?

I'm doing

```
import nltk
content_french = ["Les astronomes amateurs jouent également un rôle important en recherche; les plus sérieux participant couramment au suivi d'étoiles variables, à la découverte de nouveaux astéroïdes et de nouvelles comètes, etc.", 'Séquence vidéo.', "John Richard Bond explique le rôle de l'astronomie."]
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/PY3/french.pickle')
for i in content_french:
        print(i)
        print(tokenizer.tokenize(i))
```

But I get non-tokenized output like

```
John Richard Bond explique le rôle de l'astronomie.
["John Richard Bond explique le rôle de l'astronomie."]
```

Comment: Off-topic: NLTK is a very outdated package that shouldn't be used for any work these days. If you want a modern solution with better models, try [spaCy](https://spacy.io/models/fr)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`tokenizer.tokenize()` is sentence tokenizer (splitter). If you want to tokenize words then use `word_tokenize()`:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

content_french = ["Les astronomes amateurs jouent également un rôle important en recherche; les plus sérieux participant couramment au suivi d'étoiles variables, à la découverte de nouveaux astéroïdes et de nouvelles comètes, etc.", 'Séquence vidéo.', "John Richard Bond explique le rôle de l'astronomie."]
for i in content_french:
        print(i)
        print(word_tokenize(i, language='french'))
```

[Reference](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-ii-sentence-tokenize-and-word-tokenize)

Answer (score 6):

The issue with this Tokenizer is that it is not an effective tokenizer for french sentences :

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
content_french = ("John Richard Bond explique le rôle de l'astronomie.")
word_tokenize(content_french, language='french')
>> ['John', 'Richard', 'Bond', 'explique', 'le', 'rôle', 'de', "l'astronomie", '.']
```

`"l'astronomie"` should be tokenized as `["l'", 'astronomie']`.

You can build a better tokenizer using the `RegexpTokenizer`, as follows:

```
from nltk import RegexpTokenizer
toknizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'''\w'|\w+|[^\w\s]''')
toknizer.tokenize(content_french)
>> ['John', 'Richard', 'Bond', ...,"l'", 'astronomie', '.']
```

Comment: Dear @J.Doe, thanks a lot for your answer! Could you please elaborate a bit more regarding the content of the regexp? E.g. what does ''' stand for at the beginning and at the end? Thanks!

Comment: @TommasoDiNoto nothing special, it could also be "..." (or any other way to not break the apostoph)